# Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) - 9F34 tag from APDU command- Android

Tags: android

I'am new to EMV transactions. I want to send following tags to the server.
I have successfully retrieved EMV card data except CVM.

```
9F03    - 06    - 000000000000
5F2A    - 02    - 0458  
9C      - 01    - 00  
9A      - 03    - 181105 
9F1A    - 02    - 0458 
5F34    - 01    - 01  
82      - 02    - 1800 
84      - 07    - A0000006150001 
9F02    - 06    - 000000000000 
9F26    - 08    - 5B37BDFB97A10EC5 
9F27    - 01    - 80 
9F10    - 20     - 0FA501A201C0000000000000000000000F000000000000000000000000000000 
9F34    -------------------------------------
9F37    - 04    - 057BF277 
95      - 05    - 8000008000
9F36    - 02    - 00D0
```

How Do I get ***9F34*** tag?

Comment: Could you please provide any code you've tried with so far

Comment: Using several APDU commands I could get above tags. following are some APDU commands.                         Request :"00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100"              "00A4040007A000000003101000"

Answer (score 3):

9F34 is a the Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results tag, and so is dynamically produced by the terminal, as it describes the outcome of the Cardholder Verification step performed by the terminal, and is not sourced directly from the card.

[image: CVM Results - EMV 4.3 Book 4 - Coding of Terminal Data Elements - A4]

So, you need to perform CV, then construct 9F34 so as to reflect the outcome.

Check out CVM Results - EMV 4.3 Book 4 - Coding of Terminal Data Elements - A4 for more details.